# C: pointer arithmetic not working when done through a function call?

Tags: arrays, pointers, math, 2d

I have a dynamically allocated "matrix", allocated like so:

```
int **m = (int **) malloc (sizeof (int *) * rows);
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    m[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof (int) * cols);
```

I would like to "truncate" this matrix, by that I mean suppose  I had something like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

, truncating it by 1 row would give me :

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I can do this quite easily by

```
m++;
rows--;
```

which produces the desired result, however if I were to move the above two statements into a function like so:

```
void truncate (int **m, size_t *rows)
{
   m = m + 1;
   *rows = *rows - 1;
}
```

it doesn't work as expected. The following call

```
truncate (m, &rows);
```

produces

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

What could I be doing wrong ? The reason I want to do this is to generalize this and allow any number of rows to be truncated, so I could add a third parameter and increment `m` and decrement `*rows` by that number.

Comment: Why is `rows` of type `size_t`? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be of a numeric type?

Comment: I have seen people prefering `size_t` when working with lengths of arrays. Also the number of rows cannot be negative so `size_t` would be appropriate no?

Comment: It would make sense if you were measuring the *size in bytes* of a row, which I presume is not the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of `truncate`, you have to increment the value of the original `m`. That means passing m *by reference*, not by value. Therefore, you have to use `int ***m`:

```c
void truncate (int ***m, size_t *rows)
{
   (*m)++;
   (*rows)--;
}
```

Comment: Ok I get it, in my case, the local copy of `m` was being increment instead right ?

Comment: Correct! Don't worry, it's very common to forget about that. I'd advise reading some good explanations on the difference between passing by value and by reference. As you can see, this is essential!